# python version interpretation indiscrepencies

Tags: python

i am following along with the online book "data science from the command line" by ___. i have no experience with python, so am unfamiliar with it's syntax and interpretation intricacies.

while running this code, copied verbatim from the book:

`

```
import sys

CYCLE_OF_15 = ["fizzbuzz", None, None, "fizz", None,
               "buzz", "fizz", None, None, "fizz",
               "buzz", None, "fizz", None, None]

def fizz_buzz(n: int) -> str:
    return CYCLE_OF_15[n % 15] or str(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        while (n: sys.stdin.readline()):
            print(fizz_buzz(int(n)))
    except:
        pass ´
```

i encounter this error in python 2

```
File "fizzbuzz.py", line 8
    def fizz_buzz(n: int) -> str:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax´
```

and this error in python 3

```
´  File "/home/wan/saved-websites/datascience/ch04/fizzbuzz.py", line 13
    while (n: sys.stdin.readline()):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax´
```

why am i getting different error references for different versions of python? i assume that it's because of the order the interpreter reads the file, but a definitive answer would be better.

Bonus points: explain why the code itself doesn't run. using these two error messages i've managed to triangulate that the error has to do with how n is assigned or referenced with the colon : operator. is my hypothesis correct?

Comment: You are using Python 2, which does not support function annotations. Use Python 3, and I suggest reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: `while (n: ...)` is just wrong. It's likely  a typo for `while (n := sys.stdin.readline()):`

Comment: Python 3 was not created with back-compatibility with Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fizz_buzz(n: int) -> str:
```

This syntax is not supported in Python 2. Python added the type hint syntax in version 3.0

```
while (n: sys.stdin.readline()):
```

This is nonsense in any Python version. My *guess* is that the author intended to use the [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) operator introduced in Python 3.8 (affectionately called the *walrus operator*). That would look like

```
while (n := sys.stdin.readline()):
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast! XD

Comment: Thanks, i'll submit an issue to the author.

Comment: Is that what you are using? https://datascienceatthecommandline.com/2e/chapter-4-creating-command-line-tools.html#processing-streaming-data-from-standard-input - if so, the code is correct there.